# My brother's son 4 years older

Tags: grammar

What do I call my brother's son, who is 4 years older than myself?

I was on a visit to Canada and immigration officer asked me who am I visiting and I told him my Nephew but he is older than me, the immigration officer told me he is my Uncle. Please help me out.

Comment: That is BS. Your brother's son is your nephew regardless of your ages

Comment: You mean your **brother's** son, don't you? He is still your nephew regardless of his age, the officer probably thought you were confused, perhaps you have a foreign accent. BTW There is no capital letter for *nephew* and *uncle*.

Comment: This isn't really a grammar question, it's vocabulary. And you should be able to answer it using any dictionary.

Comment: Laura, to be absolutely clear, yes, it's "nephew" as you said.  Just as Mari explains, it's just a mix-up.  What you would say is: **"This is my nephew. Surprisingly, he is older than me, but yes he is my brother's son."**

Comment: It's just ocurred to me that maybe this is a problem of pronunciation. It's important when speaking to pronounce clearly the possessive **'s** form. My "brother son" will sound peculiar, security officials in airports are not known for their sharp wits.

Comment: Right. Try this one Laura:  "I am 20 years old.  My brother, **Steven** is 39 years old.  My brother **Steven** has a son. The name of the son is **John**.  John is 22 years old.  **This is John, here!**"  Slowly explain **each name** and **each age**.

Answer (score 5):

If he is your brother's son, then he is your nephew. From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/),

> [**nephew**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nephew)   *noun*
>
> a son of one's brother or sister or of one's brother-in-law or sister-in-law

Also, there was no need to volunteer additional information. You should have said you were there to visit your nephew. Or just *family*.